# Loop through folder names via %PATH%

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-interface, batch-processing

I'm expecting to get all folders stated in %PATH%, yet I get only the first one.
What is missing to get desired output?

```
for /f "delims=;" %%G in ("%PATH%") DO (
  echo %%G
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
for %%a in ("%path:;=";"%") do @echo %%~a
```